# python - print the sum of items in list whose total is the largest and is odd

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

It's a simple problem I have been trying to solve. First of all I take input with a list of positive integers. I want to choose items from them in such a way that their total is maximum possible and their sum is odd. If no combination is possible I want to print `-1`. I have written the code and it is not working properly.

```
l = sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))

if sum(l)%2 == 1:
    print(sum(l))

else:
    m = 0
    for x in range(len(l)):
        a = l
        a.pop(x)
        if sum(a)%2 == 1 and sum(a) > m:
            m = sum(a)
```

For example, for the input `2 3 4 5`, it's printing `9` where it should print `11`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by: *in such a way that their total is maximum and their sum is odd.*? Does not *total* mean *sum*?

Comment: Think in another way to do calculation. The maximum, but odd, is the maximum minus the minimum to be odd. Your program do it's job : 2 + 3 + 4 = 9... If I add 5, I have a odd number, so, don't add it... So return 9. It's not the good algorithm to do the job

Comment: @A.H. Yes, I feel so. But still I'm not able to think of any such algorithm.

Comment: Others have addressed better algorithms.  However, the posted code does not compile - there are indentation errors.  Also you need `a = l.copy()`, otherwise each iteration just shortens the same list and the index eventually runs out of range.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I had realised that error and have already made that change in the file in my computer. The indentation error might have creeped in when I pasted my code on the site. Anyway, now I'm using poke's algorithm.

Comment: Then you should update the question to reflect that, otherwise it is not much use to future visitors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, from the list of numbers, you want to get the largest possible sum which is odd. This is actually rather simple and can be solved pretty easily. What you need to do is take the sum of *all* numbers as that is the maximum sum that you could possibly get from those numbers. Now, we have two options:

1. The sum is odd: In that case, we’re already done. The largest possible sum is also odd, so we have our result.
2. The sum is even: In that case, we have the largest possible sum but we are not odd. In order to fix that we need to remove the *smallest* odd number from the sum. So we look at the sorted list of numbers and pick the first odd number from it. By removing an odd number from an even sum, we get an odd number again, and since we picked the smallest possible number, we know our new sum is the largest odd sum. So that’s the result.

In code, this could look like this:

```
def largestOddSum(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)
    if s % 2 == 1:
        return s

    for x in sorted(numbers):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            return s - x

    return -1
```

Used like this:

```
>>> largestOddSum([2, 3, 4, 5])
11
```

Answer (score 3):

In a easy way :
sum all and subtract the minimum odd number if first sum is even :

```
if sum(l)%2 == 1:
    print(sum(l))
else:
    print(sum(l) - [i for i in sorted(l) if i%2==1][0])
```

Comment: This calculates the sum twice and in the even case also iterates the whole list of numbers again. And then it subtracts the second smallest number…?

Comment: This also throws an `IndexError` for lists of only even numbers (e.g. `[2, 4]`).

Comment: True, but it wanted. I don't want to give a "perfect" solution to an academic problem. ;)

Comment: The result is still wrong. For OP’s example your solution is giving 9 instead of 11.

Comment: bad copy/paste from my editor. Sorry. index[0] not [1] :'(. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to tackle this is by remembering that:

```
even + even = even
odd + even = odd
odd + odd = even
```

With this in mind, you can always include all even numbers. You can also always include all odd numbers, as long as the number of odd numbers is not even. If the number of odds IS even, just leave the smallest out.